# Windows vScrollBar Equivalent in Mac OSX

Tags: c#, objective-c, nscontrol

Does anyone know what is the equivalent of the vertical scroll bar from Windows in Mac OSX?  I saw there is NSStepper.  But I can't seem to change the display of it at run time.

```
NSStepper *stepperBar = [[[NSStepper alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(0, 100, w, h)] autorelease];
```

The w and h do not seem to affect the width and height of the NSStepper object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NSSlider is what you probable want.

Comment: With NSSlider, one needs to hold down and move... I am looking for a control that has two up/down pointers.